# Changing font type within strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

Ok, so I'm familiar with how to change font types etc. for android development.  But, I can't find a way to do it with this example.

**The code for string.xml**...

```
<string-array name="help_labels">
    <item> item 1</item>
    <item> item 2</item>
    <item> item 3</item>
    <item> item 4</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="help_txt">
    <item> item 1 description: blah blah blah blah</item>
    <item> item 2 description: blah blah blah blah</item>
    <item> blah blah blah blah</item>
    <item> blah blah blah blah</item>
</string-array>
```

**the xml layout...**

```
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/helpDetailText"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:background="@layout/rectangle_border"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="17.0sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</TextView>
```

**Java code..**

```
public static final String HELP_TEXT = "helpText";
item = getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(HELP_TEXT);
    TextView helpDetailText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpDetailText);
    if (item != null) {
        if (isHtmlHelpText) {
            helpDetailText.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.toString()).toString());
        } else {
            helpDetailText.setText(item.toString());
        }
    }
```

**What I'm trying to do..**

So basically the labels lead to a detail page for each item.  I can't seem to find a way to change the font type within the description..  I would like to organize the paragraphs with bold headings before each paragraph.  This seems simple (and it probably is), but I can't figure it out.  I tried `html` tags (`<b> label </b>`) but that didn't work either.

Comment: post what you tried with html (and of course you used Html.fromHtml ?)

Comment: Sorry for confusion re-posted..